# Simple rewrite if a word is present in a url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have about 100 urls which are like these:

```
http://example.com/en/contact-us
http://example.com/en/about-us
```

When the someone clicks on any of them, it should the same page but with a parameter that has been appended

for example :

```
http://example.com/en/contact-us?language=en
```

How would i go to solve this? I am tring to write something generic that will do the job for the 100 urls i have.

This is what i have got :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /en/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}/?language=en
```

Answer (score 1):

Internal redirection: URL in the browser doesn't change

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)/([^/]+)/? $1/$2?language=$1 [L]
```

External redirection: URL in the browser changes to new URL

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)/([^/]+)/? $1/$2?language=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Please try this

Comment: Can you please check the error log file to know the reason for internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have forgotten to put a `.php` file extension at the end?

This will match any two-letter language folder followed by another directory, as long as there is no period.

```
RewriteRule ^/(\w\w)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/$2.php?language=$1
```

Be sure to test it with your URLs at [regex101](http://regex101.com).